# Is there an alternative screensaver app for Windows?

Tags: windows

I've had enough of Windows' built-in screensaver.

I have a simple requirement: turn off the screen after X minutes of idle, which I define as:

- No keyboard and mouse input.
- No app is in full-screen mode.

Currently, it gets easily upset, e.g., by:

- The xbox controller generates random clicks.
- A game that runs in full screen but is currently suspended.

Then, I need to do something about the device or exit the game.

Is there an alternative app?